# When and where to use 'sanguine' in the most appropriate way?

Tags: word-usage

I received an email from a client that he was 'sanguine' with the offer made. I understand he felt positive about the prospects of the offer as mentioned in various English language dictionaries. Similarly, is it acceptable to use something like "I adore your sanguine attitude and approach in dealing with..."?

Comment: When you checked definitions of the word, what did you find?

Comment: We like to help. Let us know of any remaining difficulty once you have consulted a dictionary.

Comment: Is it ok to use something like "I adore your sanguine attitude and approach dealing with..."

Comment: Welcome! 1) Instead of adding information through comments, please edit the question itself so that it shows that you’ve looked the word up and what you found, but also 2) it sounds like your question is mainly about context. Please give the full context of the usage, if the question is whether it was appropriate.

Comment: _Adore_ is definitely not the right word in this context. Apart from its literal meaning of _worship_, it is used in the context of personal feelings. I would suggest _appreciate_.

Comment: I very much appreciate your advice.

Comment: If I had read that, I would believe they had been raked over the coals during the process. The sense is bloodied in battle, but having survived to fight again. People in a hospital's surgical recovery room are sanguine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Sanguine* is an odd word. It has fallen out of use in English and has meanings other than *pleased* or *cheerful* related to redness, blood, and temperament.  It’s probably unfamiliar to most readers or would seem formal and stilted, so there may be no good time and place to use it.

See this NGram. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sanguine%2Cpleased&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csanguine%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpleased%3B%2Cc0